Embed option not working on YouTube share
When ever I click on embed option in YouTube share video option, no embed code is shown in fact the window what pops up upon clicking share closes and nothing happens
I was expecting a embed code to appear open clicking embed in YouTube share

first check by right clicking your mouse button inside the video player box and select the copy embed code, paste it in the notepad or any editor, there you can access the code, if this isn't working some video owners doesn't allow a user to access the embedded code by default.

Thanks my buddy, embedding the code by this method worked perfectly. Now i think something is surely wrong with my share button as i cant access the embed code using the share button option

You're welcome, maybe try accessing it in a private tab or different browser
